# Does Rotor Scoring caused by old brakepads warrant rotor replacement?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, integra

95 Integra LS brakepads have scored the rotor:

[image]

Does the scoring warrant replacement?  If I must go through the trouble of taking the part out for resurfacing, I am inclined to install a new $25 rotor.

To see the scoring, be sure to zoom in as much as possible.

Rotor removal instruction video: https://youtu.be/AGXe_Si-5l4?t=121

Comment: It was the backing plates that caused the scoring - not the pads. They were long gone... measure the rotor thickness that will tell you and fwiw I would replace them as they are cheap. Mind you have you dealt with that broken bolt yet?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, your assessment is in all likeliness correct.  I have purchased the rotors (~$25) and intend to replace the rotors, especially if it is not overly difficult / time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

To get the best performance from your new brake pads, you either need to resurface (if the disks are thick enough) or replace the rotors. You *could* run them as is, but again, you'd not be getting the best performance.

My own personal preference is to replace the rotors. The reason being is simple. New rotors aren't really that expensive. If you calculate in how much time and expense it takes to take the old rotors somewhere to have them machined, along with the inconvenience of having the vehicle down while you are waiting on the machining ... having it done on your schedule is invaluable.

Comment: @Paulster2   Always good to hear from you.  I came to the same conclusion.  I have the car jacked up and must also deal with a sheared screw, so I have resigned to the fact that this is  going to take much longer than I expected.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/224286/56573